# report error as soon as one routine encounters error

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I am trying to figure out the basic pattern for reporting an error as soon as one routine encounters an error. This is the basic logic of the code that i am working with

```
func doSomeWork(num int, errChan chan <- error) {
        if num >= 10 {
                errChan <- errors.New("Greater than 10")
        }
        return
}

const numWorkers int = 25

func run() error {
        var wg sync.WaitGroup
        errChan := make(chan error)
        for i := 0; i < numWorkers; i++ {
                wg.Add(1)
                go func(num int) {
                        defer wg.Done()
                        doSomeWork(num, errChan)
                }(i)
        }
        go func() {
                wg.Wait()
                close(errChan)
        }()
        err, ok := <-errChan
        if !ok {
                return nil
        }
        return  err
}
```

This is working as expected, it returns nil when numWorkers < 10 and error when numworker is >= 10. I dont actually care about the number of workers, this is just a simple example. However, it does not feel very idiomatic and there might be some routine leaks when one routine fails as others are still running and the routine that waits for all of them is still running too. Is there a more idiomatic way to do this which also stops all routines once one routine fails?

Comment: You're asking for a more idiomatic approach, but Stack Overflow isn't really appropriate for code reviews; you can try your luck at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Other than that, you're correct to suspect the possibility of a goroutine leak: the max of 0 and `numWorkers - 10` goroutines will leak. One easy way to avoid it would be to use an appropriately buffered channel.

Comment: Besides, the semantics of your program don't require you to close `errChan`, since you don't need to drain it. Finally, check out https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sync/errgroup, which is an abstraction over this pattern.

Comment: Correction: the max of 0 and `numWorkers - 10 - 1` goroutines will leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is close, but leaks goroutines when more than one error is sent. The first worker to send `errChan` exits because the main goroutine receives that value.  All other workers that send to `errChan` block forever because there is not a goroutine to receive the value.  The  `wg.Wait(); close(errChan)` goroutine also blocks forever waiting for the workers to complete.

The fix is two-fold: use a non-blocking send to the channel and ensure that `errChan` can receive at least one value.

See the comments below for more details:

```
func run() error {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    // Create channel with capacity one to ensure that
    // a goroutine can send to the channel before this
    // goroutine is ready to receive.
    errChan := make(chan error, 1)  // <-- note 1 here

    for i := 0; i < numWorkers; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(num int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            doSomeWork(num, errChan)
        }(i)
    }
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        // All goroutines are done, but the main goroutine
        // will be waiting if there were no errors.  Close 
        // the channel so that the main goroutine receives
        // a zero error value.
        close(errChan)
    }()
    // The if statement in the original is not needed because
    // the zero value of the error interface is nil. 
    return <-errChan
}


func doSomeWork(num int, errChan chan<- error) {
    if num >= 10 {
        select {
        case errChan <- errors.New("Greater than 10"):
             // Successful send on channel
        default:
             // Channel is not ready. This implies that
             // at least one other goroutine sent an error
             // to the channel.  There's nothing for us to
             // do here. error.
        }
    }
}
```

[Run the program on the Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/RhAIJBlKz6G)!